# How to make a token request in R?

Tags: r, post, oauth-2.0, token, httr

Trying to get an access token for an API so I can use R to pull the data. The documentation I'm using has the following instructions:

> The following POST request shows the format of an Axon Evidence token request:
>
> ```
> POST /api/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 
> Host: api.evidence.com 
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> grant_type: client_credentials&partner_id={partner ID}&client_id={client ID}&client_secret={client secret}
> ```
>
> Note: ensure that you use URL-encoded forms for all parameter values. The client secret is base64 encoded and therefore usually end in an equals sign (=), which must be encoded as %3D. Additionally, if you use a manual REST client for testing, ensure that you know whether the client is automatically performing URL encoding. For more information, see Resources.

I'm trying to request a token using the httr package with the instructions above and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using:

```r
Token_Response <- POST("https://api.evidence.com/", body = "POST /api/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
     Host: api.evidence.com 
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     grant_type=client_credentials&partner_id={partner ID}&client_id={client ID}&secret={client secret}")
```

Unfortunately I can't make this question reproducible for security reasons, but I'm hoping it's just a syntax problem on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually work directly with the body or headers when using HTTR. The function can do most of the formatting of the request for you. A proper translation would look more like

```
url <- "https://api.evidence.com/"
partnerId <- "my partner ID"
clientId <- "my client ID"
clientSecret <- "my client secret"

token_Response <- POST(url,
     encode="form",
     body=list(
       grant_type = "client_credentials", 
       partner_id = partnerId,
       client_id = clientId,
       secret = clientSecret
     )
)
```

I used a few variables for clarity but you could put the values directly in the function call if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble interpreting what I get back when I type use content(Token_Response). 

When I use read_html(content(Token_Response)) I get 

"Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')""

Comment: I have no idea what’s being returned. But you usually don’t use read_html() around the content() call.

Comment: I think it's a 'file not found' error, TBH. str(content(Token_Response)) gives the following:

List of 2
 $ node:<externalptr> 
 $ doc :<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"

and as_list(Token_Response_Content) gives. . .a lot, but when you scroll down to $html$head$script[[1]] it shows, in part:

 "\n        var URL_HOMEPAGE = \"/axon/dashboard\";\n        var EVIDENCE_NOT_FOUND = \"/axon/evidence-not-found\";\n        var EULA_URL = \"/index.aspx?class=UIX&proc=ConfirmEula\";\n

Comment: The documentation says it should look like this:

{ "access_token": "{token}", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": "{number of seconds that the token is valid}", "expires_on": "{the UNIX time after which the token will not be accepted}", "not_before": "{the UNIX time before which the token will not be accepted}", "version": "1", "entity": { "type": "AuthClient", "id": "{client ID}", "partner_id": "{agency ID}" }

I think I may be at a point where I just have to contact the owners of the site. I was hoping this was just an R problem. Thank you for your time!